# Absorption of UV Light and what color would be seen?

Tags: photochemistry, spectrophotometry, light

I am mathematically experimenting with different wavelengths of light that a fictional material would absorb. I thought of a material that absorbs a wavelength of $\pu{193 nm}$. This wavelength corresponds with the area of ultraviolet light. I am having trouble figuring out what this material would look like to a human eye. I understand that human eyes cannot see UV light. **My question is, what color would this material appear as?**

Comment: Ordinary window glass absorbs 193 nm light. So, if that glass does not fluoresce, i.e., emit light that has wavelength(s) in the visible spectrum (nominally 400 to 700 nm), then you see nothing different than normal.

Comment: Is it a math model of an ideal material which solely absorbs at a given wavelength, or a real-life example of a material with possible reflection, scattering, photoluminescence, …?

Comment: The wavelength is the ArF excimer laser wavelength, used in excimer laser lithography. Curious question about a deep UV wavelength.

Comment: If it is daylight you won't typically see any fluorescence. The fluorescence is happening of course, it's just swamped by the daylight that you see coming from whatever.

Comment: FYI Sunscreen absorbs UV light.

Comment: Oxygen and nitrogen molecules both absorb in the ultra violet below 200 nm where our eyes certainly cannot detect photons. If you could only see down there the sky would look black. If you look at a uv light source (besides  damaging your cornea) what you see is fluorescence, probably from the tryptophan and other aromatic molecules  in the proteins of the eye.

Comment: Kōan: What is the color of the light that is not seen?

Comment: If you have a mathematical material which only do that, then you see nothing by eyes.